# Ajax data not shown in console log but give error as given "http://localhost/IFICSV3/public/sla/sla/getbranch/180 not found "

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I try to make dropdown option dependent using ajax . i want to see the data in console whether the data is success or else. I expect the data was shown in console log but error given

> http://localhost/fic/public/sla/sla/getbranch/180 404 not found

Here is my code for view ajax

```js
if(country_id) {

    //console.log(country_id);

    $.ajax ({
        url: 'sla/getbranch/'+country_id,
        //url: "{{ route('sla.getbranch') }}"+country_id,
        type: 'GET',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
```

My controller

```
public function index()
{
    $custList = $this->hdcustomermaster->getAllCustomerActiveSts();
    return view('sla.slm.SLAList', compact('custList'));
}

public function getbranch($id)
{
    $data=HDCustomerBranch::where('cb_customer_ID',$id)->pluck('cu_customer_ID','cu_customer_Name');
    return json_encode($data);
}
```

my web.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'sla'], function () {

   Route::get('/','SlaController@index');
   Route::resource('sla', 'SlaController');
   Route::get('sla/getbranch','SlaController@getbranch')->name('sla.getbranch');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your route like this

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'sla'], function () {

   Route::get('/','SlaController@index');
   Route::resource('sla', 'SlaController');
   Route::get('sla/getbranch/{id}','SlaController@getbranch')->name('sla.getbranch');
});
```

Here the problem is you are passing 180 as an param in that route. But you dont declare that param in your route.
Also you can add a '?' if it is an optional param, like this

```
Route::get('sla/getbranch/{?id}','SlaController@getbranch')->name('sla.getbranch');
```